# Join 2 mssql queries

Tags: sql, ms-sql

I need to join to MSSQL queries, but I am not getting anywhere with this.

Both queries return a single value:

```
 SELECT COUNT(*) FROM sysjobhistory WHERE run_status <> 1 AND step_id = 0;

 SELECT MAX (run_date) FROM sysjobhistory WHERE run_status = 1 AND step_id = 0;
```

I am a total SQL noob so any help is appreciated

Comment: Do you want both values returned in a single query from the sysjobhistory table?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's hard to tell what you want the output to be, but I think this will help you:

```
DECLARE @Count INT
DECLARE @MaxRunDate DateTime -- I'm guessing run_date is a datetime... 

SELECT @Count = COUNT(*)
    FROM sysjobhistory WHERE run_status <> 1 AND step_id = 0;
SELECT @MaxRunDate = MAX(run_date)
    FROM sysjobhistory WHERE run_status = 1 AND step_id = 0;

SELECT @Count, @MaxRunDate
```

There are other ways to do this, including using a JOIN, but I believe the above is easier to understand, particularly for beginners.

Comment: Thanks, this will do. All I needed was to have both values returned from one query. It is for a nagios plugin, that needs both values to perform its check

Answer (score 2):

If you want to union, name the columns:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) AS 'Column' FROM sysjobhistory WHERE run_status <> 1 AND step_id = 0
 UNION
SELECT MAX (run_date) AS 'Column' FROM sysjobhistory WHERE run_status = 1 AND step_id = 0
```

If you want the two columns on the same query you can use sub queries:

```
SELECT (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM sysjobhistory WHERE run_status <> 1 AND step_id = 0) AS 'Count', (SELECT MAX (run_date) AS 'Column' FROM sysjobhistory WHERE run_status = 1 AND step_id = 0) AS 'Max'
```